# How can I animate an View and its NavigationBar with CGAffineTransformMakeScale

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation

Im trying to animate my containerView when present other one in the middle of the screen. But I do not get it. If only animate the view, the navBar dont do nothing, if I animate both it dislodges.

[When I only animate the view its look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqdeI.jpg)

[When I animate the navigationBar its look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDKu7.jpg)

An this is my code

```
 let datePickerController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DatePickerViewController") as! DatePickerViewController
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: datePickerController)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
    navController.transitioningDelegate = self

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 0.5
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.alpha = 0.5
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
        //NavigationBar animattion
       // self.navigationController!.navigationBar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
        self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }) { (Bool) in

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I fix it, the solution is change this lines

```
    self.view.alpha = 0.5
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.alpha = 0.5
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
    //NavigationBar animattion
   // self.navigationController!.navigationBar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
```

by these

```
  self.navigationController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.93, 0.93)
  self.navigationController!.view.alpha = 0.5
```